# i just make a register forum but validation doesnot work. I get following errors:BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2071:

Tags: php, laravel-5

Whenever I try to register form I get same error. Its been an hour but could not figure out. My validation does not working.

Even though I fully posted the register form it still shows same error.

What actually BadMethodCallException and that builder.php line 2071 that is out of my knowledge. I have following error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::validate()
```

Here is my User@Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use View;
use App\Basemodel;
use App\user;
use Input;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
     public $restful = true;

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('users.new')->with('title', 'Make it snappy Q&A - Register');
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        $validation = User::validate(Input::all());

        if($validation->passes()){
            User::create(array(
                'username'=>Input::get('username'),
                'password'=>Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
                ));
             return Redirect::to_route('home')->with('message','Thanks for registering!');
        } else{
            return Redirect::to_route('register')->with_errors($validation)->with_input();
        }
    }
}
```

and my Basemodel is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use user;

class Basemodel extends Model
{
    public static function validate($data){
        return Validator::make($data,static::$rules);
    }
}
```

and my user model is:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Basemodel;

class user extends Model
{
    public static $rules = array( 
    'username'=>'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    ); 
}
```

Comment: Can you post the full stacktrace? Can you show us the exact code where the stacktrace is failing at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are receiving that error because in your `user` model, you are extending the `Model`. You have defined your `validate` method in `BaseModel`. So to rectify that error, do the following:

Replace this line:

```
class user extends Model
```

With this line:

```
class user extends BaseModel
```

And the error should disappear.

**Just a Side Note:**

I don't know why you are doing in that way, but the correct way would be to create the FormRequest object.

Fire the following command from the terminal:

```
php artisan make:request YourFormRequest
```

The above command will create the file called `YourFormRequest` in `app/Http/Requests` folder. Open that file in your editor.

Now, in the `rules` method, pass all the validation rules. So, in your case it would be like this:

```
/**
 * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'username'              => 'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
        'password'              => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
        'password_confirmation' => 'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    ];
}
```

Now in your controller, update the `create` method to the following:

```
/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 * Import the YourFormRequest class
 *
 * @param \App\Http\Requests\YourFormRequest $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Redirect
 */
public function create(YourFormRequest $request)
{
    User::create($request->all());

    return redirect('home')->with('message','Thanks for registering!');;
}
```

In order to hash the password, update the `User` model to this:

```
/**
 * Hash the password attibute before saving in database.
 * 
 * @param string $password
 */
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = bcrypt($password);
}
```

With the `setPasswordAttribute` method, you don't have to worry about the hashing of password manually as laravel is smart enough to hash it with the above code.

Hope this helps you out. Cheers.

Comment: Yes u are right.I can use Request method.I just copied all of your code but when i set to check validation it shows foridden but not the validation as suggested by u @user3514160

Comment: That is because in the same file, there is a method called `authorize`.. You need to replace `false ` to `true`.. And the error should disappear..

Comment: yes it works.Thank you @user3514160 if any problem rises i will sure contact uh.

Comment: Sure.. No problem.. Glad to hear that.. Happy coding.. Cheers.. :)

Comment: After sumitting the form i get this error:   QueryException in Connection.php line 651:
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `username` = anandshrestha57)

Comment: That is because there is no username column in your database table.. Check it in mysql or in phpmyadmin..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98368/discussion-between-anandshrestha57-and-user3514160).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `user` model. Your model should look like this instead:

```
namespace App;

class user extends Basemodel
{
    public static $rules = array( 
    'username'=>'required|unique:users|alpha_dash|min:4',
    'password'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation'=>'required|alpha_num|between:4,8'
    ); 
}
```

You where extending the Eloquent Model instead of your own Basemodel. In this case you can also get rid of your `use` statements as the `user` model is in the same namespace as your `Basemodel`.

Comment: The BadMethodCallException is a standard PHP exception which you can find more info on here [PHP Docs](http://au1.php.net/manual/en/class.badmethodcallexception.php)

Comment: Thank you . I did it but still FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 45: Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Redirect' errors shown up.Can you suggest how to resolve this

Comment: That's a completely different issue of which you have not supplied enough info. A stack trace would be handy!